# How to dynamically render styles by session or cookies

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session, cookies

I have defined different bundles for my stylesheets.
And I tried to do something like this: in the `_Layout.cshtml`

```
@if (Session["UserId"] == null)
{
    Styles.Render("~/Content/Darkly");
}
else
{
    var User = Model.Single(x => x.UserId.ToString() == Session["UserId"].ToString());
    Styles.Render(string.Format("~/Content/{0}", User.Settings.Style));
}
```

But that does not work for some reason.
Is there another way to do the same?

Here is the `BundleConfig.cs`

`

```
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                  "~/Scripts/respond.js"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                  "~/Content/site.css"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/Darkly").Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap-darkly.css"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/Cosmo").Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap-cosmo.css"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/Lumen").Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap-lumen.css"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/Cyborg").Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap-cyborg.css"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/Readable").Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap-readable.css"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/Cerulean").Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap-cerulean.css"));
```

`

Comment: Can you share your BundleConfig.cs? I suspect that you don't have those user specific styles configured in your app.

Comment: In case of UserId equal to "Foo", you have to have a bundle configuration like this:

```cs
            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/Foo").Include(...)
```

Please refer to this [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification#using-bundling-and-minification-with-aspnet-web-forms-and-web-pages) on how to configure bundles.

Comment: No, I don't think so. I use the UserId to find the User and then use that users preferences to set the bundle. The `User.Settings.Style` contains the last part of the bundles virtual path

Comment: BundleConfig looks correct. I tried it on my machine and it works. Check the following:

1. Order of the css files
2. Name of the style actually matches the name in the bundle

Comment: The Names do actually match. But why Ordor of the css files? And Where? In the code (bundles) ?

Comment: while debugging vs tells me that `Session["UserId"]` is `null` so the first block should be executed, but thats not what happens :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I know what is wrong here, you should add '@' symbol before the render.

like this:

```
@if (Session["UserId"] == null)
{
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css");
}
else
{
    @Styles.Render(string.Format("~/Content/{0}", "Darkcss"));
}
```

This will actually make Razor to render the output of the Render method.

Comment: this should work but now I get Errors for this line `var User = Model.Single(x => x.UserId.ToString() == Session["UserId"].ToString());`  LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Object get_Item(System.String)' method but almost the exact line is in my AccountController for Login.

Comment: Try extracting "Session["UserId"].ToString()" in a variable before the LINQ statement and use the string variable in the LINQ itself.

var idFromSession = Session["UserId"].ToString();
Model.Single(x=>x.UserId.ToString() == idFromSession)

Although I recommend to avoid doing queries to DB from the view. It would be better to extract the user in controller and set the CurrentUser on the HttpContext.